# How long to increase my sneak skill?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

My sneak skill is currently 49 and I want to get it to 100. Keeping my joystick pushed forward while unseen, how long would it take to get to 100? I'm playing on Xbox.

Answer (score 0):

I myself have had a problem with sneak but using sneak attacks is one very effective way (especially if you have 15x damage). However with a reasonable pickpocket skill you can train with Delvin in the thieves guild and simply pickpocket the gold back, amd if you're already a member of the guild he will not become hostile of you are caught. And obviously just sneaking around ruins etc.

Answer (score -1):

If you just sneak around a lot and do stealth kills it would go pretty fast. But if you pay somebody to teach you, you could get to 100 in no time.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm on my computer with a different character. On my Xbox he's just in a corner sneaking. Would that help level it up fast?

Comment: I don't think so. I'm pretty sure you actually have to go around and be stealthy to level up. If someone was trying to kill you while you were hiding in the corner, it would help.

Comment: Thanks. I think that would help because it only went to 68 in one hour